# access an element inside of an iframe inside of a jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to "load a page" inside of a page that the user is already on instead of redirecting them to that new page.  It is my understanding that an iframe is the best way of doing this.  I like jQuery's [dialog box](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) as a wrapper for this iframe content, as it looks nice and allows the user to reposition the popup as well as close it easily.

I'm having trouble accessing the elements on this iframe however.  I want to be able to take data from the user's original window and add it to the new iframe's input elements, but I can't seem to find the syntax for doing this.

There is something in the code for the iframe page that overwrites jQuery's use of `$`, so I can't use `$('#foo').text('bar')`.  I've been trying to find the correct syntax in pure javascript - like

```
var a = window.frames["e_frame"].document.getElementById ("title");
a.text = 'foobar';
```

where `e_frame` is the id I've given to my iframe, and `title` is the id of an element that loads in the iframe.  I can see these both clearly in the developer console, but I cannot access them and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Typing in the command above in the console gives me this error:

```
VM364:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:28
```

and typing `window.frames` into the console to debug myself gives me way too many lines to go through since I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: And is the page in the iframe from the same domain, using the same protocol and port, as the parent page.

Comment: The iframe is from a different subdomain (a.mydomain.com vs b.mydomain.com) - I'm loading it via Apache ProxyPass - prior to putting it through a proxy I was getting the CORS error, but since I put it through the proxy I can now load the page and interact with it using the mouse and keyboard like normal, but can't access it directly through code.

Comment: I tried the same approach with a different page on my same subdomain and I'm able to access the page's elements via javascript.  I guess it is a CORS issue.  Darn it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("e_frame");
var iframe_contents = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('title');
```

Comment: `undefined` for `var iframe = document.getElementById("e_frame");`

Comment: i did a mistake.  Is  dialog > iframe > element right ?